# amortized analysis on a binary heap

Tags: data-structures, amortized-analysis

So a regular binary heap has an operation extract_min which is O(log(n)) worst time. Suppose the amortized cost of extract_min is O(1). Let n be the size of the heap

So a sequence where we have n extract_min operations performed and it initially contained n elements. Does this mean that the entire sequence would be processed in O(n) time since each operation is O(1)?

Comment: This might be a better question for cs.stackexchange.com. Either way - if you run n O(1) operations, then yes, that takes O(n). If you somehow end up with every extract_min op taking O(log n), then you'd get O(n log n).

Comment: Who says that extract_min has amortized O(1) cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets get this out of the way first:  Removing ALL the elements in a heap via `extract_min` operations takes **O(N log N)** time.

This is a fact, so when you ask "Does constant amortized time `extract_min` imply linear time for removing all the elements?", what you are really asking is "Can `extract_min` take constant amortized time even though it takes **O(N log N)** time to extract all the elements?"

The answer to this actually depends on what operations the heap supports.

If the heap supports only the `add` and `extract_min` operations, then every `extract_min` that doesn't fail (in constant time) must correspond to a previous `add`.  We can then say that `add` takes amortized **O(log N)** time, and `extract_min` take amortized **O(1)** time, because we can assign all of its non-constant costs to a previous `add`.

If the heap supports an **O(N)** time `make_heap` operation (amortized or not), however, then its possible to perform **N** `extract_min` operations without doing anything else that adds up to **O(N log N)** time.  The whole **O(N log N)** cost would then have to be assigned to the **N** `extract_min` operations, and we could *not* claim that `extract_min` takes amortized constant time.

Comment: "If the heap supports only the add and extract_min operations, then every extract_min that doesn't fail (in constant time) must correspond to a previous add. We can then say that add takes amortized O(log N) time, and extract_min take amortized O(1) time, because we can assign all of its non-constant costs to a previous add." if its this, the insert taking O(log(n)), then would it take O(n) time for n operations?

Comment: nope.  The N extract_min operations take O(N log N) time as I said.